# drcsim problem to show ground truth odometry by rviz

Tags: odometry, rviz, drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

It seems there is a problem to show ground truth odometry by rviz. In rviz, I have added the odometry and the topic `ground_truth_odom`. However, there is an error in Transform.

The error code is
`Transform [sender=/gazebo] For frame [/world]: Frame [/world] does not exist`

How can I solve this problem and show the `ground_truth_odom` in rviz?

Thanks,
Weiwei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1590/drcsim-problem-to-show-ground-truth-odometry-by-rviz/) by [weiweihuang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/236/weiweihuang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[ticketed](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/144/create-ground-truth-odom-transforms-form), please follow up there.  thanks.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0